"pywhatskit" on python not sending message updated
I tried to use pywhatskit (on multiple screens) and my message was not send.
Below are my code, a mix of answers I saw on a similar post that worked for me.
The browser window must be on the same screen as the python script because of GUI interaction
import pywhatkit as kit
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import time
import keyboard as k


win = Tk() # Some Tkinter stuff
screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth() # Gets the resolution (width) of your monitor
screen_height= win.winfo_screenheight() # Gets the resolution (height) of your monitor


phone_number = "+123456789123" #number with country code
message = "Hello from Python! This is an instant WhatsApp message."

kit.sendwhatmsg_instantly(phone_number, message, 5, False, 3)

time.sleep(10)

pyautogui.moveTo(screen_width * 0.694, screen_height* 0.904) # Moves the cursor the the message bar in Whatsapp
k.press_and_release('enter')

